# Apache re-write rule for new connections only

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I've been following the following guide to control whether or not to display a maintenance page.

https://www.shellhacks.com/redirect-site-maintenance-page-apache-htaccess/

I would only like Apache to re-direct new connections to the maintenance page though, users currently on the site should be able to continue as normal until they close connection. How would I do this in Apache?

Comment: What do you mean about the connection? The current HTTP connection or the current session on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.htaccess is constantly read and applied, so you can't do it with .htaccess

But your description fits perfectly with a new configuration change "elsewhere" other than htaccess, which needs a restart.

Apache has a "**graceful restart**" in which active connections get the old config while new connections get the new config.